# How can I configure the path where Doctrine place the Repository files?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I think the subject says it all. Working with Symfony, when creating entities with "doctrine:generate:entity", how can I change the default path where Repository files are created.

There must be sort of a configuration file, but I can't find it.

In the same way, is there any parameter for indicating where to place the backup "*.php~" files when "doctrine:generate:entities" is executed? I think they are necessary, but I don't like them to appear in the same path as the "good ones".

Thanks in advance!

Pedro

Comment: I normally just add *.php~ to my .gitignore and my IDE's ignore settings. So I hardly ever notice them.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yep, I already have done that. But I was thinking of a way to make them don't even appear. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you have a subdirectory inside Entity folder you can specify the path like this:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle:directory_name --env=local
```